# Table storage key as a message into the Azure queue

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm able to insert the rowkey and partition key into Azure table storage:

> TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);
>   table.Execute(insertOperation);
>   StoreKeyInQ(insertOperation);

```
// Create a new customer entity.
        CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("URL", "Name"+Guid.NewGuid());
        customer1.path = fullpath;
```

The "CustomerEntity" is as below:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public CustomerEntity(string ID, string Name)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = ID;
            this.RowKey = Name;
        }

        public CustomerEntity() { }

        public string path { get; set; }


    }
```

I have written code to create a queue as below:

```
 public void StoreKeyInQ(TableOperation insertOperation)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        //craete a queue client
        CloudQueueClient cloudQueueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        //retrive a reference to a container
        CloudQueue cloudQueue = cloudQueueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
        //create the queue if does not exists
        cloudQueue.CreateIfNotExists();

       // Create a message and add it to the queue.
       CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(insertOperation); //Here is the error as "CloudQueueMessage" can't take a argument type "TableOperation"
       queue.AddMessage(message);
    }
```

How to resolve this error? How to pass both "rowkey" and "partition" key of table storage into a Queue?

```
  EDIT:
```

I have added these two lines for serialization is this OK?

```
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(customerEntity.GetType());
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(x.ToString());
```

My queue is showing like this; however, not sure if this is correct or not? Can anyone please clarify- Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do! Are you trying to insert a message in a queue (then why create this whole table thing) or are you trying to insert an entity into a table (then why this whole queue thing)?

Comment: Basically idea is to store both RowKey+PartitionKey in the queue and create a worker role to retrieve the key (RowKey+PartitionKey ) from the Queue.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for your `Customer` model. Essentially you will need to serialise your model as string and then save that as a message. On the receiving end, you will again deserialize it and get the object and from there you can retrieve the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` values.

Comment: You're trying to insert a custom object into the queue, which only accepts byte arrays or strings. You need to change this (e.g. send  JSON, csv, any other serialized-to-string or serialized-to-byte-array format).

Comment: @GauravMantri I have edited the question as per your instruction.Hope my edit is proper.

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve this error?

If we want to insert the message in to the queue. We could get the operation queue

code demo from [Get started with Azure Queue storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue)

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("RowKey, PartitionKey ");
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

> How to pass both "rowkey" and "partition" key of table storage into a Queue?

You could serialise your model as string and then save that as a message or you could use your customize format to save the message such as message format: `RowKey, PartitionKey`

> Basically idea is to store both RowKey+PartitionKey in the queue and create a worker role to retrieve the key (RowKey+PartitionKey ) from the Queue.

If you just want to retrieve queue message, there are many  cheap ways we could use, such as [Webjob queue trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues) or [azure function queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function).

**Update:**

Please have a try to use the following code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer1));
cloudQueue.AddMessage(message);
```

[image]

For more demo code please refer to [SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) or [Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) an Object.

Comment: The OP already has info on inserting into a queue. The issue is that they are trying to insert a custom object, where queues only handle byte arrays or strings. Also, the "how to handle queue message" part is out-of-scope for the question (well, it's ambiguous at best).

Comment: I have updated my question with "CustomerEntity". Could you please provide more clarification about your answer?

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to  Serialize or Deserialize Object.